# Android TableLayout - shrink a bit more

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to place several text elements in a single row and exactly one of those elements is considered "active". So I have the following two cases:

- Total width of all text elements is less than parent width. Just show all text elements as-is.
- Total width exceeds parent width. Show the full text of "active" element without any clipping, use ellipse to shrink all other text elements.

Let's assume it is guaranteed that if there is just one element, it always fits.

List of strings is dynamic. Any element could be set "active" at any moment.

So far I have the following: a table layout with a single row, all "inactive" columns are set shrinkable and text elements are set to be ellipsized in the end. The "active" one is setEllipsize(null) and the column is not shrinkable.

The problem is that all shrinkable columns are shrinked to some fixed percentage but not more. If that's not enough to let "active" text to be shown, the whole table is clipped to parent width.

So the question is if I'm missing some way of controlling how much columns can be shrinked.

P.S. All layout is generated by code, not using layout xmls.

Comment: So I decided to implement my own ViewGroup with custom onMeasure which would force all inactive elements to be shrinked while keeping the total width. Then I decided I don't actually need the whole feature that would use this shrinkable row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shrinking your elements you might be able to either use layout weights, or if even better you can just set the visibilities of the view to INVISIBLE or GONE. But if you still need to display the entire row of text, you can just keep all the rows the exact same.
Then when a view is active you can just overlay another view on top using a relative_layout that is the full text. So you would be basically using a pop-up window effect kinda.

Comment: Problem with weights is that strings could be very different. Short strings require little space, long strings need more. This means that weights have to depend on string lengths, right?

Comment: Yep. Things can get a little ugly. I would just recommend keeping all your items the same. Size and ellipse=true. Than just put another view on top to highlight what the user selected. This way they can still see all the other entries

Comment: I also want them to be clickable, not just visible.